# Google Analytics: User-scoped Custom Dimension is not being tracked Cross-Domain

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, universal-analytics

**Situation**

I have two domains, example1.com and example2.com

example1.com is my lander and I'm doing a/b testing on it. Right now I have a User-scope Custom Dimension setup to track this. This is tracking fine and is set for every user.

```
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
  ga('require', 'linker');
  ga('linker:autoLink', ['example2.com'] );
  ga('set', 'dimension1', 'XX');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

example2.com is my checkout provider's page. I'm tracking pageviews and ecommerce on this page. This is tracking fine.

```
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
  ga('require', 'linker');
  ga('linker:autoLink', ['example1.com'] );
  ga('send', 'pageview', '/orderstatus');

  ga('require', 'ecommerce');
  ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
    ...
  });
  ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
    ...
  });
  ga('ecommerce:send');
```

**Expected**

When viewing an ecommerce or site content report with my custom dimension as a secondary dimension, I should see a breakout out with views or purchases by different lander versions.

**Result**

Any time I add my custom dimension as a secondary dimension to a report that is based the example2.com domain, the report shows 0 hits/purchases.

Any ideas? I'm not sure where I'm going wrong as each part is working individually.

Comment: How long has it been since you set this up? Has GA had time to populate? Are you able to set your custom dimension successfully as a secondary dimension in reports from example1.com?

Comment: Oh..one thing that i've run into before for clients...is if they forgot to setup their referral exclusion list...have you done that?

Comment: @kevindeleon It's been a couple days. The custom dimension is working for everything except the example2.com pageviews/events. And my referral exclusion list is set with example1.com (default) and example2.com. For some reason it just appears that the user-scope is not working cross-domain.

Comment: That is interesting...it does look like everything is setup properly...maybe there's a limitation with user scoped dimensions. Without knowing what information you're gathering for your dimension, could it possibly make sense to try a session scoped dimension instead? I've honestly never tried either. I know custom events and virtual pageviews work fine across domains with the same kind of setup though.